# PHP on command line displays "Out of Memory"

Tags: php, command-line-interface, out-of-memory

This is not the normal fatal error when you run out of memory in a script, as it doesn't give a file name, a line number or the amount of memory used. It simply says "Out of memory" whenever I try to run php on the command line, either when you pass it a script or simply just run php by itself. Even trying to run a script that doesn't exist gives the same message.

In other words I get this:

```
dan@server [~]# php
Out of memory
dan@server [~]# php test.php
Out of memory
dan@server [~]# php doesntexist.php
Out of memory
dan@server [~]# php -v
Out of memory
```

However PHP through Apache works absolutely fine. It's just on the CLI that I get this error.

The machine in question is running CentOS release 5.7 (Final) and PHP 5.3.10.

**EDIT:** I have just tried running ulimit -a as root as suggested and this is the output:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 1000000
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 37888
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 4096
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 14335
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not PHP failing, but the kernel preventing you to use a process using too much memory. Use `ulimit -a` to see which limits are set. You can then augment them, since you're root.

Okay, that wasn't it. Attemtp #2: Use `free -m` to see how much memory left you have. Another process is probably eating too much of it, and we're going to make sure this is the issue by using `free`.

Comment: I have run this and detailed above but I don't really understand what each option means or which one might be affecting it.

Comment: Edited. Also, I think you would be better of submitting this question to ServerFault.

Comment: Posted at http://serverfault.com/questions/368780/php-on-command-line-displays-out-of-memory-no-file-name-line-number-or-memor